# mex error 206 Matlab

Tags: c++, matlab, mex

The cpp code I received for a project isn't working so I want to compile and see if it compiles. It didn't compile, but I tried compiling another cpp file that I know works just to see what would happen. In both cases I get the following error:

```
EDU>> mex max.cpp
xcodebuild: error: SDK "macosx10.7" cannot be located.
xcrun: error: unable to find utility "clang++", not a developer tool or in PATH

mex: compile of ' "max.cpp"' failed.
```

Any suggestions how I can either fix the cpp file or maybe I'm not running this correctly? Can't figure out where to go from here.

***EDIT***:
I figured it out. My mexopts.sh file was pointing to an old version of mac so I had to manually edit that file and change 10.7 to 10.9.

Comment: Did you already do `mex -setup`?  What was the output?

Comment: @chappjc 
When I try to setup the compiler it gives me the options:
 `The options files available for mex are:`
`1: /Applications/MATLAB_R2013a_Student.app/bin/mexopts.sh : 
      Template Options file for building MEX-files`
     0: Exit with no changes`

So I choose 1 and I've tried mex filename.cpp again and the same error. 

Though admittedly I'm not sure if I'm setting up mex correctly

Comment: So I guess you don't have Xcode installed.  [Get it, install it](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/downloads/), and try again.

Comment: no I do have Xcode installed and currently running.

Comment: @user3528438 mex -setup cpp is the same as mex -setup and both give me basically the option for the compiler being `1: /Applications/MATLAB_R2013a_Student.app/bin/mexopts.sh : 
      Template Options file for building MEX-files` or nothing. I choose that and rerun mex but I still get the same error.

not sure if that's what I should be getting or not, but either way it's still not working

Comment: You can post your edited solution as an answer to your own question and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. My mexopts.sh file was pointing to an old version of mac so I had to manually edit that file and change 10.7 to 10.9.